# ActionController::ParameterMissingが改善されない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

strongparamaterをprivateメソッド以下に定義しているのですが、定義している値は存在しないとerrorが発生しています。

自分なりに色々調べたのですが原因がわからない為、どなたかご教示お願い致します。

[image: エラー画像]

session_controller.rb

```
class Staff::SessionsController < Staff::Base
  def new
    if current_staff_member
      redirect_to :staff_root
    else
      @form = Staff::LoginForm.new
      render action: 'new'
    end
 end

  def create
    @form = Staff::LoginForm.new(form)

      if @staff_login_form.email.present?
      staff_member = StaffMember.find_by(email_for_index: @staff_login_form.email.downcase)
    end
    if staff_member
      session[:staff_member_id] = staff_member.id
      redirect_to :staff_root
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
end

  private

  def form
    params.require(:form).permit(:email, :password)
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% @title = 'ログイン' %>

<div id="login-form">
  <h1><%= @tittle %></h1>

  <%= form_for @form, url: :staff_session do |f| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :email, 'メールアドレス' %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :password, 'パスワード' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div>
     <%= f.submit 'ログイン' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: フォームを表現しているファイル(ビューテンプレート)の内容が欲しいところですね。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました！viewファイル追加しました。なにかアドバイスがあればご指導ご鞭撻の程、よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/127029

Answer (score 1):

インデントを修正してみてください。

```
class Staff::SessionsController < Staff::Base
  # ...
end

private

def form
  params.require(:form).permit(:email, :password)
end
```

こんなコードになっています。`form` メソッドが class 定義の外にあるのが原因ではないでしょうか?